# Can we have a "header bar" like area 51?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

When I am not signed into area51, I see a read bar on top of the page that says:

> Welcome to Area 51, the Stack Exchange Q&A site creation zone – check out the FAQ!

I believe this is useful for encouraging users to see the FAQ, which on here (Islam.SE) it would seem not many look at the FAQ before asking or answering questions/participating.  So I would like to request that we get something similar for this site that says something like:

> Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, the Stack Exchange Q&A site on Islam - Please check out the [FAQ](https://islam.stackexchange.com/faq)

I think it should appear of course when people aren't signed in, and I think it should appear for new users, at least until they get a certain amount of reputation.

Comment: Actually I'm surprised it doesn't exist by default, I usually see it in other SE sites.

Comment: IIRC you now get a blue notification when you join the site.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to have to mark this as declined.

Area51 is on a slightly different codebase for lots of historical reasons. The large red bar you see on there is actually [a historical artifact we deliberately removed from the network](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/) and replaced with the blue notifications circle in use today.

While we appreciate what you're asking for, it's technically already there. When new users first log into the site, they see a box on the right-hand side of the page explaining what/who the site is for. Here's what yours looks like:

[image: salaam]

Comment: ah ok.  It is nice to to know regarding that, I now understand.